# How could I save new objects when form is closing?

Tags: c#, winforms

I wrote a code that it creates a new buttons when clicked. But I want to save new buttons settings (in a file maybe), sizes etc. After form closed they should be saved and we should be able to see them again when re-opened. How can I do this ?

Thanks...

Comment: By writing code...

Comment: @L.B Absolutely, but which codes i should write ?

Comment: Take a look at using settings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @L.B that will hardly help him... You could save the relevant properties of the created objects, and reload them at startup. Also, and more important, read our community's asking guidelines in order for us to better help you.

Comment: @user3366576, are your buttons in an array or list? if so, you could loop through it and save all the settings (properties) to a file.

Comment: @user3366576 It can be :) Actually i want to write their settings to array. But they are not in array now.

Comment: @user3366576 `but which codes i should write` C# codes. We can continue this conversation until you post **what you have tried so far** and ask in which part you have the problem. SO is not *"write the code for me"* site

Comment: @3366576 No I am also use c# but i meant how could i do this :)

Comment: @L.B Sorry brother. You are right. But I cant do this part. I tried so many codes but they were not work. My codes are not so long and trust me they are not important. So this is unneccessary..

Comment: @user3366576 - Your code is absolutely important. To get good answers it is necessary to show your work.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class the wraps button.  (WrappedButton)

So it takes the button as a parameter to a constructor.

Add properties to this class that you want to save.  Height, Width, text, Left, Right etc.

In the constructor set the fields on your class from the fields on the button.

Put all of your WrappedButtons into a list.

Use the following code to save and load a List to and from a file.

```
   public static void SaveListOfT_ToFile< T >( List< T > l, string filename )
   {
      Type[] extraTypes = new Type[1];
      extraTypes[ 0 ] = typeof ( T );

      XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer( typeof ( List< T > ), extraTypes );

      using ( StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter( filename ) )
      {
         xs.Serialize( writer, l );
      }
   }

   public static List< T > LoadListOfT_FromFile< T >( string filename )
   {
      try
      {
         Type[] extraTypes = new Type[1];
         extraTypes[ 0 ] = typeof ( T );

         XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer( typeof ( List< T > ), extraTypes );
         List< T > a;

         using ( FileStream f = new FileStream( filename, FileMode.Open ) )
         {
            // Use the Deserialize method to restore the object's state with
            // data from the XML document. 
            a = ( List< T > )xs.Deserialize( f );
         }


         return a;
      }
      catch ( Exception )
      {
         return null;
      }
   }
```